# Why aren't the prompt doing the work it's supposed to achieve?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

Working on a chatbot on Lex amazon, and have set `Date`,`Time`, `location` parameters i have set the prompt to ask when they're not supplied according to the slot type.

When i give a wrong or bad date values like `sughdfusf` or `ice cream` or such it asks for the value again , same with time but it isn't the case with location as it takes completely random values not defined in the slot type `AMAZON.US_CITY` .How can i fix it and why is it occurring?

Comment: correct slot type for city is `AMAZON.US_CITY` **not** `Amazon.City_US`

Comment: True, i'll edit it, any clue why i'm having this issue mentioned in my question tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lex is thinking that `sughdfusf` is a city name, so it is allocating this to `AMAZON.US_CITY`.
You can either report this issue to amazon team and wait for them to fix it or you can use below workaround.

1. Untick the required checkbox from the slot
2. In the Lambda function, in `DialogCodeHook`, use some third party api to validate the city
   name
3. Return `ElicitSlot` in case validation failed

Hope it helps, let me know if you have further doubts.

Comment: I can't seem to find the DialogCodeHook

Comment: you have to write code for that. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/using-lambda.html

Comment: I have just checked the docs, a lambda function is a must their right? Like it can't be done on let's say Python.

Comment: you can write Lambda functions in many languages, and yes you can write it in Python. Follow this example to create Lambda function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-bp-create-lambda-function.html